# tsc-watch kills redis connection between app and redis server

Tags: typescript, tsc, bullmq

I am trying to get ts-watch to work on a nodejs/typescript project which is using bullmq.

The application is a simple API which does some long running calculations. These calculations are by the cueue manager bullmq.
Right now I am having the problem, that when I first start the dev environment via: `yarn watch`

```
"watch": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node ./dist/app.js\" --onFailure \"echo Beep! Compilation Failed\" --compiler typescript/bin/tsc",
```

it works and the application runs. When I then change something in the code it acts as supposed and checks for errors. BUT also kills the connection between bullmq and redis.
--> this happens when I change something.
09:33:00 - File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

```
SIGTERM signal received: closing queues
All closed

09:33:04 - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

from now on there is no connection between the bullmq queue and the app, and following jobs never finish.

What can be the issue here? did someone managed to have a bullmq / tsc-watch project up and running?

any help would be great! Thank you so much!